# Should I specify key-type and value-type when using ECache in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I've seen a lot of articles where those parameters where specified, like that:

```
    <cache alias="dishDTOs" uses-template="default">
    <key-type>java.lang.Integer</key-type>
    <value-type>com.topjava.graduation.restaurant.dto.DishResponseDTO</value-type>
</cache>
```

But what is the point of it? Everything seems to work even without them, moreover, if i specify these I have this exception

```
Invalid value type, expected : com.topjava.graduation.restaurant.dto.DishResponseDTO but was : java.util.ArrayList
```

Methods under test ( just call these 2 one by one ):

```
        @Cacheable(value = "dishDTOs", key = "-2")
    public List<DishResponseDTO> getAll() {
    // code
}
    @Cacheable(value = "dishDTOs", key = "#dishId")
    public DishResponseDTO getOne(int dishId) {
    // code

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use two different caches. In the first case, you are trying to save a list (return type of the `getAll` method) into a cache specified for individual `DishResponseDTO`s. That's why you get the exception.

If you don't specify the types, the cache will assume `Object`, so you won't have any type safety. See, for example, [Ehcache docs](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/getting-started.html#configuring-with-xml).

Comment: So the only reason to add these is type safety?

Comment: Yes. The docs say it "guards the cache from being polluted by random types." So it allows you to be sure what type of objects you get from the cache and prevents accidental caching of incompatible data by at least failing in a predictable way.